# Mass ID3 renaming

Tags: mp3, rename, id3

I have a whole bunch of unnamed mp3s.

I need to name them all, preferably with the same name as their file name.

so for soundeffect001.mp3, it should name id3 title the mp3 as soundeffect001.

Because all the files are in the pattern soundeffect###, something that simply numbers mp3s is just fine too.

Anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/download.html) to rename your mp3 files massively and easily. I've been using it for years and it is very comfortable. Further info:

Mp3tag is a powerful and yet easy-to-use tool to edit metadata of common audio formats where it supports ID3v1, ID3v2.3, ID3v2.4, iTunes MP4, WMA, Vorbis Comments and APE Tags.

It can rename files based on the tag information, replace characters or words in tags and filenames, import/export tag information, create playlists and more.

Mp3tag supports online database lookups from, e.g., Amazon, discogs, or freedb, allowing you to automatically gather proper tags and cover art for your music library.

**Main features:**

- Batch Tag and Filename Editing
- Support for Cover Art
- Import from Amazon, discogs, freedb,
  MusicBrainz
- Replace characters or words
- Create Playlists automatically
- Rename files from tags
- Export to HTML, RTF, CSV
- Full Unicode Support

Comment: If you rename your files (using a batch renamer) to differentiate the file numbers (e.g. to soundeffect_001.mp3) before using Mp3tag's 'Filename to Tag' function you can also do things like add the Track number tag (%title%_%track%) etc.